# Formula para Calculo em jQuery com retorno

Tags: jquery

Tenho esta listagem... Preciso que, ao preencher o valor real, eu faça:
(valor real) - (valor de compra) = compra-versus-real, e o lucro é (compra-versus-real) - (valor de venda), e preencher o lucro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas queria em tempo real, preencher, fazer a operação e retornar o resultado.

Estrutura HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="50" class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Item do Pacote</th>
            <th>Compra</th>
            <th>Venda</th>
            <th>Real</th>
            <th>Compra <i>versus</i> Venda</th>
            <th>Compra <i>versus</i> Real</th>
            <th>Lucro</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php 
    if(count($detalhes_evento->detalhes_pacote_ativo)>0){
        $total_compra = 0;
        $total_venda = 0;
        $total_compra_versus_venda = 0;
        $compra_versus_venda = 0;
        foreach($detalhes_evento->detalhes_pacote_ativo as $valor){ 


            $compra_versus_venda = ($valor->valor_venda - $valor->valor_compra);        

            $total_compra += $valor->valor_compra;
            $total_venda += $valor->valor_venda;
            $total_compra_versus_venda += $compra_versus_venda;


    ?>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><?php echo $valor->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $valor->nome; ?></td>
            <td class="valor_compra">R$ <?php echo number_format($valor->valor_compra, "2", ",", "."); ?></td>
            <td class="valor_venda">R$ <?php echo number_format($valor->valor_venda, "2", ",", "."); ?></td>
            <td width="110px"><input type="text" id="valor_real" name="valor_real[]" class="form-control valor_real" placeholder="0,00"></td>
            <td><?php echo number_format($compra_versus_venda, "2", ".", "."); ?></td>
            <td class="resultado">0,00</td>
            <td>0,00</td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="50" class="text-center"></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>R$ <?php echo number_format($total_compra, "2", ",", "."); ?></th>
            <th>R$ <?php echo number_format($total_venda, "2", ",", "."); ?></th>
            <th>R$ 0,00</th>
            <th>R$ <?php echo number_format($total_compra_versus_venda, "2", ",", "."); ?></th>
            <th>0,00</th>
            <th>0,00</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>    
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="text-center">Nenhum item foi adicionado a este pacote.</td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Tentei fazer desta forma:

```
$(".valor_real").on('keyup', function(){
    var valor_compra = parseFloat( ( $(this).parent().parent().find(".valor_compra").text() ).replace("R$ ", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", ".") );
    var valor_venda = parseFloat( ( $(this).parent().parent().find(".valor_venda").text() ).replace("R$ ", "").replace(".", "").replace(",", ".") );
    var valor_real = $(".valor_real").val();
    var lucro_base = (valor_compra - valor_real);
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".resultado").html( "R$ "+lucro_base );
})
```

Mas infelizmente, a primeira linha, dá certinho.. mas as outras, não, os valores não são retornados corretamente.

O que tem de errado?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode atribuir ao seu campo `real` a função [`.change()` do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$( "#campo_real" ).change(function() {
  // faça o calculo e atualize o valor no proximo campo
  ...
  $( "#meu_outro_campo").val(meu_valor_calculado);
});
```

Essa função pode ser atrelada quando sua página carregar, no famoso [`.ready()` do jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // minha função começa abaixo
});
```

Comment: Leve em consideração, que os campos são em formato array(), então, neste caso não consigo pegar pelo id do campo e sim pelo class... Mas de igual forma, não dá certo. Os campos são em array() para salvar no banco de dados estas informações posteriormente.

Comment: Você quer dizer que as linhas da tabela são um array? Você pode fazer um `for` no seu array e usar o mesmo contador

Comment: Sim, todos eles são array, conforme o meu post.

Comment: Não tem que fazer um `parseFloat` no `valor_real` também? Se quiser simplificar sua função pra extrair somente os números, tente: `minha_string.replace( /^\D+/g, '');` que substitui tudo que não for número por 'nada'. O que o console.log mostra pro `valor_venda`?

Comment: Da mesma forma, se eu colocar o parser, ele não retorna o valor correto nas outras linhas, apenas na primeira. http://prntscr.com/daw3ul